# How to use multiple values for an exposed filter via url

Tags: views, services

On my current setup I'm exposing a view that outputs json through a service.

The view can be called like this: `http://domain.com/api/books.json`.

I also exposed a filter to a referenced content type "Author". I'm **NOT** using `context filters`, I'm using the regular `Filters` and exposed that particular filter to the user, this way I can give my filter a nice argument name `author_nid`.

So now I can call this: `http://domain.com/api/books.json?author_nid=38`. And this returns all books of the author with that nid.

But I can't seem to figure out how to get the list of books of both author 38 or author 32.

The things i tried:

`http://domain.com/api/books.json?author_nid=38,32`

`http://domain.com/api/books.json?author_nid=38+32`

`http://domain.com/api/books.json?author_nid[]=38,32`

`http://domain.com/api/books.json?author_nid[]=38+32`

`http://domain.com/api/books.json?author_nid[0]=38&author_nid[1]=32`

I seem to have the feeling that this isn't supported right now. Am I correct? If so, what are my options? I'd like to give my arguments a name because I'm about to expose 10 to 15 filters (some optional, others required). Using context filters and filtering like this: `args[]=2&args[]=43,23&args[]=44` isn't very readable/maintainable.

Comment: It is rather strange that the list of filters for **Content: Nid** doesn't include "is one of" like a lot of the others do.

Comment: indeed, one of my frustrations atm :p

Comment: See [Metal Toad: How to Pass Multiple Values through an Exposed Filter in Drupal Views](http://www.metaltoad.com/blog/passing-multiple-values-through-exposed-filter), especially the part where he implements `hook_views_query_alter`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If using `?author_nid[]=38&author_nid[]=32` as suggested by [milkovsky](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/103100/292) doesn't work you may need to look at using contextual filters. Or, as I think might be your only option, use [hook_views_query_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_query_alter/7) where you can build your own views query WHERE clause based on $_GET parameters.

Comment: Please check the comment on milkovsky's answer. Sadly enough it's not working. Using context filters isn't really an option, check my initial question. Any references or examples how I should write such a hook? Never did this before :p

Comment: I commented a little bit too fast. I now see the link thirdender posted as a comment on my question. I'll try that first.

Comment: Using `?author_nid[]=38&author_nid[]=32` worked for me. This is the only documentation I could find on it too...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's just a problem with encoding.
I've the same construction (views with multivalued field in exposed filter), and here is the result when I apply the submit button:

http://mywebsite.com/search-housing?field_rooms_value%5B%5D=1&field_rooms_value%5B%5D=2

Could you try this and tell me if it's working?

http://domain.com/api/books.json?author_nid%5B%5D=38&author_nid%5B%5D=32

Comment: Thanks for the reply but this isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Christian and MPD, there is no "is one of" option for NID.
Christian's answer about hook_views_query_alter will work.

As alternative solution - you can replace filter handler with a custom one. 
Here is solution for search API query. Next handler will use "Allow multiple selections" option:

```
class MYMODULESearchApiViewsHandlerFilter extends SearchApiViewsHandlerFilter {

  /**
   * Extends query to handle multiple values.
   */
  public function query() {
    if (!empty($this->options['expose']['multiple'])) {
      $values = array();
      // ...
      // DO YOUR CODE HERE TO GET VALUES FROM $this->value
      // E.g. $values = explode(',', $this->value);
      // ...
      if (!empty($values)) {
        $or = $this->query->createFilter('OR');
        foreach ($values as $value) {
          $or->condition($this->real_field, $value, $this->operator, $this->options['group']);
        }
        $this->query->filter($or);
      }
    }
    else {
      parent::query();
    }
  }

}
```

You can add your handler using hook_views_data_alter().

```
/**
 * Implements hook_views_data_alter().
 */
function MYMODULE_views_data_alter(&$data) {
  $data['search_api_index_MYINDEX']['MYFIELD']['filter']['handler'] = 'MYMODULESearchApiViewsHandlerFilter';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass multiple values using contextual filter,

Select Raw Value from Url and select PathComponent/arugument.

Below we have **More section from that you can check Allow multiple values** in the form of 1+2+3 (for OR) or 1,2,3 (for AND).

http://example.com/some-path/24+25

or

http://example.com/some-path/24,25